# Inserting a character into similar variable names across multiple data frames

Tags: r, string, dplyr, lapply

I have two data frames that have some shared variable names that need to be renamed so that there is a "/" between the base of the name and a number following that base. Here is the incredibly clunky way of doing this:

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
  rename("child_signs_sick/1" = "child_signs_sick1",
         "child_signs_sick/2" = "child_signs_sick2",
         "child_signs_sick/3" = "child_signs_sick3",
         "child_signs_sick/4" = "child_signs_sick4",
         "child_signs_sick/5" = "child_signs_sick5",
         "child_signs_sick/6" = "child_signs_sick6",
         "child_signs_sick/7" = "child_signs_sick7",
         "child_signs_sick/8" = "child_signs_sick8",
         "child_signs_sick/9" = "child_signs_sick9",
         "child_signs_sick/10" = "child_signs_sick10",
         "child_signs_sick/11" = "child_signs_sick11",
         "child_signs_sick/12" = "child_signs_sick12",
         "child_illnesses/1" = "child_illnesses1",
         "child_illnesses/2" = "child_illnesses2",
         "child_illnesses/3" = "child_illnesses3",
         "child_illnesses/4" = "child_illnesses4",
         "child_illnesses/5" = "child_illnesses5",
         "child_illnesses/6" = "child_illnesses6",
         "child_illnesses/7" = "child_illnesses7",
         "child_illnesses/8" = "child_illnesses8",
         "child_illnesses/9" = "child_illnesses9",
         "child_illnesses/10" = "child_illnesses10",
         "child_illnesses/11" = "child_illnesses11",
         "child_illnesses/12" = "child_illnesses12")

df2 <- df2 %>%
  rename("child_signs_sick/1" = "child_signs_sick1",
         "child_signs_sick/2" = "child_signs_sick2",
         "child_signs_sick/3" = "child_signs_sick3",
         "child_signs_sick/4" = "child_signs_sick4",
         "child_signs_sick/5" = "child_signs_sick5",
         "child_signs_sick/6" = "child_signs_sick6",
         "child_signs_sick/7" = "child_signs_sick7",
         "child_signs_sick/8" = "child_signs_sick8",
         "child_signs_sick/9" = "child_signs_sick9",
         "child_signs_sick/10" = "child_signs_sick10",
         "child_signs_sick/11" = "child_signs_sick11",
         "child_signs_sick/12" = "child_signs_sick12",
         "child_illnesses/1" = "child_illnesses1",
         "child_illnesses/2" = "child_illnesses2",
         "child_illnesses/3" = "child_illnesses3",
         "child_illnesses/4" = "child_illnesses4",
         "child_illnesses/5" = "child_illnesses5",
         "child_illnesses/6" = "child_illnesses6",
         "child_illnesses/7" = "child_illnesses7",
         "child_illnesses/8" = "child_illnesses8",
         "child_illnesses/9" = "child_illnesses9",
         "child_illnesses/10" = "child_illnesses10",
         "child_illnesses/11" = "child_illnesses11",
         "child_illnesses/12" = "child_illnesses12")
```

I am looking to make this code much more clean and efficient, probably using regex and the apply family, but I cannot figure out how to do it. This seems to me like something that could be done in 2 lines of code, but I'm struggling to figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rename_with` to apply a function to the column names. For example

```
# sample data
dd <- data.frame(
  id = "001",
  child_signs_sick1=1,
  child_signs_sick2=2,
  child_signs_sick3=3,
  child_illnesses1=10,
  child_illnesses2=20,
  child_illnesses3=30
)

add_slash <- function(x) gsub("(.*\\D)(\\d+)$","\\1/\\2", x)
dd %>% rename_with(add_slash, starts_with("child"))
```

Here we create a helper function `add_slash` to insert a slash before the last digits of a name. Then wen use a selector to apply that function to all names that start with "child". You can adapt that with any `tidyselect` function to choose the columns you want to transform

Comment: Super-smart! I see exactly what you did (minus the regex magic that I'll have to spend a minute untangling). One silly Q: I've been learning how to create functions lately, and usually it seems like curly brackets follow "function()" and contain the function's body. Why was there no need for those here?

Comment: @bricevk Curly braces are basically holders for one or more than one line of code. If your function body is only one line of code, then you don't require the braces to contain it. The function signature must be followed by a single expression. That expression can be a single function call, or it can be a `{}` expression which contains multiple sub-expressions.

Comment: Thanks so much! That makes perfect sense given other omissions of {}s that I have seen in other contexts.